# Antenna Design Problem

Tags: structural-engineering

I'm designing a 10'L x 10'W x 200'H end fed with a capacitance hat, that extends 4' out.

The base will be chain cradle support.
Here's what it might mean.

The base of the tower is 1' off the ground. It will look like an X with two sets arms forming a cross that nestle in-between the arms of the X.

The tips of the X will be hung while arms of the double cross will be teathered to the ground All chained to allow some movement.

Guy wires will be provided for extra stability  but allow for the tower to flex and sway to the limits of the allowance.

My concern needs to be the footers need to heavy I may need to engineer a way for when the tower leans the weight applies to the areas that are holding the tower to the ground.

Is their options that I could engineer to provide a solid grip, so the tower does not fall.

Comment: Drawing a diagram will make your question alot clearer.